# R: Can I use some sort of matrix multiplication with exponentials?

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, exponential

I have data matrix (X) of the dimensions 5000x250 plus an extra parameter Y (Dim: 5000x1). The following loop gives me the desired results, but it takes forever to compute.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(X))
  for (j in 1:nrow(X))
   {
   X[j,i]=Y[j,1]^X[j,i]
   }
```

Is there any way to optimize this? If I didn't require the exponential, I'd use matrix multiplication. Thanks!

Comment: Is X[...] an integral type (before exponentation)?

Comment: Doesn't `X^Y` work? If not, try `X^as.numeric(Y)`, vector recycling should ensure you get what you want.

Comment: X can take the value 0,1 or 2 before exponentation.

Comment: @James: I'm not sure what you're suggesting. X[] has to be the exponent.

Comment: @aciM Oops, misread the Q. In that case you need to rbind your Y's together. I'll post an answer

Comment: that would be great. As it is it would probably run for hours.

Comment: @aciM  "never say 'probably' " :-).  Try using `microbenchmark` to see how your loop performs compared with Hong Ooi's solution.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft fair enough, but it is not even close. Actually it's a bit shocking how slow the loop is.

Comment: Good work!  Never taking anything for granted is the sign of solid science (or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your column vector `y` into a matrix and use elementwise `^`.

```
matrix(y, nrow=nrow(X), ncol=ncol(X)) ^ X
```

or

```
rep(y, times=ncol(X)) ^ X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vectorised `^` if you construct a matrix of y's of the correct size:

```
x <- matrix(1:9,3)
y <- matrix(1:3,ncol=1)

do.call(cbind,replicate(ncol(x),list(y)))^x
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    1    1     1
[2,]    4   32   256
[3,]   27  729 19683
```